# Pion interaction in vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, casimir-effect, pions

Does pion zero particle $\pi^0$ (zero charge and null spin) experience casimir force?
If i wonder how pion particle with quantum electrodynamic field.

Comment: Do you mean the Casimir force as in the force between two metal plates? And can you clarify what you think the consequences of such an interaction might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pi0 decays electromagnetically into two gammas in about 10^-16 seconds from its production in strong interactions. It is a linear combination in a bound state of either u anti_up, or down anti_down

Here are the [feynman diagrams](https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~krauss/Lectures/QuarksLeptons/QCD/QuarksAndColour_3.html):

[image: pi0]

> The blob means that the quark-antiquark pair is in a bound state.

At some point in its brief life the quark meets the antiquark and annihilates through the electromagnetic interaction.

During its brief life, if higher order diagrams are included in the calculations  there may be interactions called ["vacuum interactions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_state)

> [If the quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_state#Non-zero_expectation_value) can be accurately described through perturbation theory, then the properties of the vacuum are analogous to the properties of the ground state of a quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator (or more accurately, the ground state of a QM problem). In this case the vacuum expectation value (VEV) of any field operator vanishes. For quantum field theories in which perturbation theory breaks down at low energies (for example, Quantum chromodynamics or the BCS theory of superconductivity) field operators may have non-vanishing vacuum expectation values called condensates. In the Standard Model, the non-zero vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field, arising from spontaneous symmetry breaking, is the mechanism by which the other fields in the theory acquire mass.

In QCD then i[t is possible](http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys741/xji/chapter5.pdf) that QCD vacuum affects the masses of the pions, including th pi0 but the Casimir force comes from QED where the conditions do not hold for such higher terms corrections, as far as I know.

There do seem to exist Casimir operators for the strong force too, in some models,  as [seen here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9810539)

> The Proton Spin in the Chiral Bag Model : Casimir Contribution and Cheshire Cat Principle
>    ...
>
> This enables us to obtain the hitherto missing piece in the axial charge associated with the gluon Casimir energies.

I doubt that the model has been extended to the rapidly decaying  electromagnetically pi0

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect mentions a bag model of baryons where "Casimir energy" plays an unexplained role. That might be what this is about... It reminds me of Mannque Rho writing on the 'Cheshire Cat principle'

Comment: @MitchellPorter I think that this Casimir is a QCD one,not the electromagnetic one, see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9810539 "This enables us to obtain the hitherto missing piece in the axial charge associated with the gluon Casimir energies. "

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a Casimir effect that involves gluon fields, not electrodynamic fields, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9810539).

Comment: just saw that you had found the same reference :).